# cakephp 2.1 displaying habtm list checkboxes and their assigned images

Tags: image, cakephp, checkbox, has-and-belongs-to-many

Calling all Cakephp Gurus!

Okay, this one really has me by the short and curly.

I have a habtm list within a form. When adding (add.ctp) I would like to display the mutiple checkboxes with their image references (image field name). The actual illustrations is what needs to be seen so that a selection can be made. I dont need the image to activate the checkbox. I just need to display the checkbox with the image and selecting the checkboxes would be perfect.

If anyone has had a problem like this and has come up with a solution, please do tell.

Below an example of

Kind regards all.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('ListShExPainImage', array(
        'label' => false, 'multiple' => 'checkbox'));?>
```

Answer (score 0):

$this->Form->input('ListShExPainImage', array('label' => false, 'type' => 'select', 'multiple' => 'checkbox'));